# Why my Laravel Queued Commands are getting slow over time on Redis queue driver?

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-5.5, supervisord, task-queue

I am using Redis driver to process multiple types of jobs on multiple queues and multiple queue workers. For example, Let's say I am making a monitoring Services which will monitor Server's connections and Website's uptime.

I have master command scheduled which will select the models from databases and will queue another command that will be queued. So, Let's say I have 1000 websites and 300 servers to monitor and the master command will execute every 15 minutes and it will add a total of 1000 websites and 300 servers in their specific queues (serverMonitor and uptimeMonitor).

The issue is, When I start/restart the workers I have configured using Supervisor, QueuedCommands execute very fast. Like they process all the jobs in 1/2 time. When over time, Let's say 24 hours, when I check the queues, I find thousands of unattended queued commands.

I have 8 workers running for UptimeMonitor queue and 5 workers running for ServerMonitor queue. When I start/restart the workers, UptimeMonitor would process 5-6 Queued Commands per second but after 24 hours, It would process only 1 Queued Command every 2 seconds.

I made sure I don't have `--sleep=x` flag in my Supervisor configuration. Is there anything I am missing? Have anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a rule of thumb when you have busy workers. They will start to compete for resources.

Eight workers competing for the same CPU core will get about 12.5 % of the core each.

Each worker will  'slow down' so you will not get any benefit. And you will lose performance inbetween because the OS will need to manage the scheduling of the processes, meaning you get more interrupts and context switches.

There are two measurments to look at to see if you have enough workers: throughput and latency.

> **Throughput**: are you creating new jobs faster than you can handle them
>   ? Which to me this looks the trouble that you are having. You have low
>   throughtput.

and

> **Latency**: If jobs are completed in time that you think is acceptable.

As in your case to me it looks like you have a low throughput issue suggestions:

1. General increase your hardware capacity (powerful cpu, more ram).
2. Queue the workers on AWSSQS, spread the workers on different machines.

Comment: When I restart my queue workers, everything works fine for a few hours. By fine, I mean all the jobs are processed successfully before new jobs are loaded to the specific queues. After a few hours, they slow down.

Comment: after they have spent time competing with each other they slow down the os as it tries to manage those interrupts and thats why they slow down after a time.

Comment: Okay, Got it. So Either I can upgrade the CPU or I can decrease the number of queue workers. Right?

Comment: YES. I have faced this issue before.

Comment: Hi, Just an update! Actually, there was nothing wrong with my application, Nor yours except your application needed lots and lots of resources. I explained the situation to my hosting provider. They investigated and told me I had a bad neighbour. Now they removed that bad instance and now my average server load is down by 50% (Yes, Now average is 30%) and I am running 10 workers and it isn't slowing down! It was an issue of my hosting provider.